# PHP loop problems,how do i solv this

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

Hey all i can not solve this,that's why i post it here .i am a php larner and trying solve small php problems.my problems are below.

`0
1 0 1
2 1 0 1 2
3 2 1 0 1 2 3
4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4`

how to print the following pattern ?

image link-[http://imgur.com/4Y5L8ZZ](https://imgur.com/4Y5L8ZZ)

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: actually i want to solve it...but no way ...

Comment: so what you have tried?

Comment: @robin_po I suggets you post the code you are having issues with and do your best to explain to us what you are expecting and what the problem is.

Comment: i try but no success.i use for loop and nested loop but i can`t solve.

Comment: @robin_po: paste your code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

for ($out = 0; $out < 5; $out++) {
    for ($row = $out; $row > 0; $row--) {
        echo $row . " ";
    }
    for ($col = 0; $col <= $out; $col++) {
        echo $col. " ";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked. I'm not sure whether it's the best approach.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    for ($a = $i; $a > 0; $a--) {
        echo $a;
    }
    for ($b = 0; $b <= $i; $b++) {
        echo $b;
    }
    echo "\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try executing following code snippet as a solution according to above mentioned description.

```
    $rows=5;
    for($i=0;$i<$rows;$i++)
    {
       echo "<br>";
       for($j=$i;$j>=0;$j--)
       {
          echo "\t".$j;
       }
       for($k=1;$k<=$i;$k++)
       {
           echo "\t".$k;
       }
   }
```